# Swift update value inside Dictionary<String, Any> in an Array

Tags: swift

I have an array of Dictionaries, like so

`var myArray: [Dictionary<String, Any>] = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()`

Somewhere in my class i add values there, like so:

```swift
var myDict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
myDict["Id"] = "someUniqueId"
myDict["v1"] = -42
self.myArray.append(myDict)
```

Then later i try to update the `v1` inside this dict like so:

```
self.myArray.first(where: { $0["Id"] == "someUniqueId" })?["v1"] = -56
```

However, the compiler tells me:

> Cannot assign through subscript: function call returns immutable value

Any way i can modify the value in array outside of copying the whole dictionary, removing it from array, and re-inserting?

**UPDATE** This dictionary is not strongly typed because what is inside the dictionary, both types and fieldnames, are controlled by the user in an external system. E.g. we download some metadata and then render controls for this dynamic data.

Comment: Any time you say Any alarm bells should go off. This thing with an Id and v1 should be a struct and this should be an array of that struct.

Comment: @matt that'd be great, except in this product the customer can in EXTERNAL system define whatever fieldnames in this dictionary they want with any data type they want.

Comment: "Any way i can modify the value in array outside of copying the whole dictionary, removing it from array, and re-inserting?" -> You can wrap your dict into an object (instance of a class), which can be modified in-place.

Comment: "can in EXTERNAL system define whatever fieldnames in this dictionary they want with any data type they want" Is the call-site you provided an example, or is the existence of `"Id"` hardcoded?

Comment: @Alexander `Id` is hardcoded, but `v1` is an example

Comment: @zaitsman In that case, I recommend you factor out any mandatory fields (like `Id`) into strongly typed struct/class members, and keep a dict for the dynamic values only.

Comment: @zaitsman Also, use a dictionary literal instead of creating an empty mutable dictionary and adding to it.

Comment: Even Any can be removed using some wrapper type, eg an enum with associated values, to support only specific types.

Comment: @Alexander in real code it's a `for configVal in configVals { myDict[configVal.fieldName] = someVal }` type of code which is why there is no literal.

Comment: @Sulthan the whole point is that i don't really know what they might want to put in there, though.

Comment: But you will have a list of supported types, types you know how to work with.

Comment: @zaitsman I don't see your point. The initialization pattern of a value shouldn't be what dictates it's API from then onwards. You can special-case mandatory fields and assign them to properties explicitly. The important part is that your data model will have an `id` property which is strongly typed (to avoid the `binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'String'` error). Plus then you can also conform to the `Identifiable` protocol, once that's released.

Comment: @Alexander the final result of what i do is still a Dictionary<String, Any> because this is how the sdk i have to use consumes the data. So in this specific case i figured why bother modelling. Coming from c# I am still a bit stuck on collections being value types. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @zaitsman "Coming from c# I am still a bit stuck on collections being value types." In cases when it's beneficial for them to be reference types, just wrap them in a class, like Joakim shows in his answer.

Comment: @zaitsman " the final result of what i do is still a Dictionary<String, Any> because this is how the sdk i have to use consumes the data." In that case, you can keep the dictionary for backing storage, but at least wrap it an expose mandatory fields as computed properties that access/mutate the dict, and provide the ID in a strongly typed manner, making it compatible with `==` and such.

Comment: @Alexander see this question following on from this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351147/swift4-decodable-decode-half-the-keys-as-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Swift Dictionary is a value type.
Use a custom class or you can use `NSMutableDictionary` for this purpose (because `NSDictionary` is immutable).

```
var myArray = [NSMutableDictionary]()
var myDict = NSMutableDictionary()
myDict["Id"] = "someUniqueId"
myDict["v1"] = -42
myArray.append(myDict)
myArray.first(where: { $0["Id"] as? String == "someUniqueId" })?["v1"] = -56

print(myArray)
// [{
//     Id = someUniqueId;
//     v1 = "-56";
// }]
```

Comment: Yikes, I'd quite recommend against this. `NSMutableDictionary` is slower, isn't generic, and is just an all-round bad time in Swift.

Comment: @Alexander Sure, it may be a solution not very “Swifty”. Yet it gets the job done and it is exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easier for yourself by wrapping your dictionary in a simple class

```
class Config {
    private var dict: [String: Any]

    init(_ dict: [String: Any]) {
        self.dict = dict
    }

    func valueFor(_ key: String) -> Any? {
        return dict[key]
    }

    func setValue(_ value: Any, forKey key: String) {
        dict[key] = value
    }
}
```

and use that in your array

```
var myArray = [Config]()
```

And use it like this

```
array.filter { $0.valueFor("Id") as? String == "someUniqueId" }
    .first?.setValue(-56, forKey: "v1")
```

That way you can avoid using classes like NSMutableDictionary and keeping it more pure Swift. Another advantage with a custom class is that you can add functionality to it to simplify your code using it, so for instance if you will be looking up dictionaries by "Id" a lot we can add a computed property for it

```
var id: String? {
    return valueFor("Id") as? String
}
```

and then the example above would become

```
array.filter { $0.id == "someUniqueId" }.first?.setValue(-56, forKey: "v1")
```

Comment: I could except see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351147/swift4-decodable-decode-half-the-keys-as-dictionary