# Swift4 Decodable - decode half the keys as Dictionary

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I have the situation where the server sends me a model where i know of types and names of some keys, and don't about the others. However, the user can edit those other key value pairs of their own volition.

Example:

```
{ "a": "B",
  "b": 42,
  "__customKey1": "customVal1",
  "__customKey2": [41, 42],
  "__customKey3": {"z":"x"}
}
```

So what i want to end up with is a model with some declared properties and some values stuffed into a `Dictionary<String, Any>`, e.g.

```swift
struct MyStruct {
  var a: String?
  var b: Int?
  var dict: Dictionary<String,Any>
}
```

I tried something like:

```swift
  public struct CodingKeysX: CodingKey {
      public var intValue: Int?
      public var stringValue: String

      public init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
      public init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }

      static func make(key: String) -> CodingKeysX {
          return CodingKeysX(stringValue: key)!
      }
  }

 init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let co = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeysX.self)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.a = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .a)
        self.b = try container.decode(Int?.self, forKey: .b)
        let allDeclaredKeys = container.allKeys.map({ $0.stringValue })
        self.dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
        for key in co.allKeys.filter({ !allDeclaredKeys.contains($0.stringValue) }) {
            self.dict[key.stringValue] = try? co.decodeIfPresent(Any.self, forKey: key)
        }
    }
```

But I get the following compile-time error:

> Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Decodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

It also seems that using `JSONDecoder` i can't get reference to original `Data` to us `NSJSONSerialization`. So i could, i suppose, do it the other way round where i first init the dict using the older technique, then init the model using `JSONDecoder` and replace init with something passing Data in, but it just feels wrong because we'd be effectively deserializing twice :/

Comment: I would give up and just use JSONSerialization. This JSON is unstructured; you're hosed.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that you should parse this as `[String: Any]`. There are only a handful of legal value types in JSON. That's nowhere close to `Any`.

Instead, your starting point IMO would be a [generic JSON decoder](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/d91175be2f737aca7ad476759948666e). That decodes into a `JSON` enum.

```
let value = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSON.self, from: json)
==> Optional(["__customKey1": "customVal1", "b": 42, "a": "B", "__customKey2": [41, 42], "__customKey3": ["z": "x"]])

value["a"]?.stringValue   // Note value is a JSON, not a Dictionary
==> Optional("B")
```

Using that, to solve your specific problem you could do something like this (very close to your existing decoder):

```
struct MyStruct {
    var a: String?
    var b: Int?
    var dict: [String: JSON] // JSON values, not Any values
}

extension MyStruct: Decodable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: JSON.Key.self)

        let knownKeys = [JSON.Key("a"), JSON.Key("b")]

        // Unload the known keys. There's no need for these to be Optional unless
        // they really are optional (and nil is different than ""). The point,
        // is you can do any "normal" validation you want here and throw on error.
        self.a = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: JSON.Key("a"))
        self.b = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: JSON.Key("b"))

        // Unload the rest into your dictionary
        self.dict = [:]
        for key in container.allKeys where !knownKeys.contains(key) {
            self.dict[key.stringValue] = try container.decode(JSON.self, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

let ms = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: json)
=> MyStruct(a: Optional("B"), b: Optional(42), 
            dict: ["__customKey1": "customVal1", 
                   "__customKey2": [41, 42], 
                   "__customKey3": {"z": "x"}])

ms.dict["__customKey1"]?.stringValue  // Optional("customVal1")
```

Comment: that's a neat solution, and i did come across this in my search. Unfortunately my problem is that the SDK i have to use requires `Dictionary<String, Any>` at the other end. Which is why i wanted to store my data in it anyway. If i use the `.JSON()` enum, then i have to: a) convert data from JSON to this model b) convert data to Dictionary<String, Any> to store c) to read, convert data from Dictionary<String, Any> to this model again d) to send it back, convert data to JSON. 

Genuinely - given the above, would you still choose to follow your suggested answer?

Comment: Absolutely. Conversion is trivial (`.dictionaryValue` and `init(Any)`). Even if I were going to build a custom encoder/decoder, I'd use this `JSON` enum to do all the work inside `encode(to:)` and `init(with:Coder)`.